# Paste test results in double copy

Tags: jquery

I wrote a function that takes some paragraph text, formats it and then updates the textarea. It seems to do the job, but sometimes it results in duplicating pasted text block. I even tried adding a line to remove initially pasted text. What am I missing?

Code:

```js
$("#sum").one("keyup", function() {

  var txt = "",
    str = $(this).val(),
    arr = str.split(/\n\n/);

  $(this).val("");

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var itm = (arr[i] + "<zzz>"),
      itm = itm.replace(/\n/g, ""),
      txt = itm.replace("<zzz>", `\n\n`);

    txt += txt;
  }

  $(this).val(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="sum" name="sum" rows="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: `txt += txt;` duplicates `txt`.

Comment: Don't use the same `txt` variable in the `for` loop as you use for the string that you're appending to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#sum", document).one("keyup", function() {

      var this_ = $(this);
      var txt = "",
        str = this_.val(),
        arr = str.split(/\n\n/),
        new_txt = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var itm = (arr[i] + "<zzz>"),
          itm = itm.replace(/\n/g, ""),
          txt = itm.replace("<zzz>", `\n\n`);

        new_txt += txt;
      }
      
      

      this_.val(new_txt);
        console.log(new_txt);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="sum" name="sum" rows="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: Where is the explanation regarding what you changed and why? Code only answers are not very practical and are frowned upon